# Is there any way to call LpVariables from string in PuLP optimization?

Tags: python, pulp

In PuLP optimization program, I want to call defined LpVariable value from str list.

I tried to convert 'x2' by some way, but I couldn't.
Is there any way to do this, except using many IF/ELIF list `if test_str=='x1': ...` ?

```py
from pulp import *


def pulp_test():
    # define the problem
    prob = LpProblem("The_Problem", LpMinimize)
    x1 = LpVariable('x1', 0, None, LpContinuous)
    x2 = LpVariable('x2', 0, None, LpContinuous)
    x3 = LpVariable('x3', 0, None, LpContinuous)
    prob += 3 * x1 + 11 * x2 + 2 * x3
    prob += -1 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 5
    prob += 3 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 4
    prob += 3 * x2 + 2 * x3 <= 6
    prob += 3 * x1 + 5 * x3 >= 4
    status = prob.solve()

    test_str = 'x2'

    print("type(x2): ", type(x2))
    print("type('x2'): ", type(test_str))

    print("value(x2): ", value(x2))
    # want to call LpVariable from str list
    print("value(convert from str 'x2'): ", value(pulp.LpVariable(test_str)))

pulp_test()
```

the result is,

```
type(x2):  <class 'pulp.pulp.LpVariable'>
type('x2'):  <class 'str'>
value(x2):  0.0
value(convert from str 'x2'):  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `LpVariable.dicts` method. It will create a dictionary of variables. Here is an example where it is used: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html

From that example:

```
from pulp import *
Ingredients = ['CHICKEN', 'BEEF', 'MUTTON', 'RICE', 'WHEAT', 'GEL']
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients,0)
```

Then if you do:

```
ingredient_vars['CHICKEN'] # you get the variable for chicken
```

Comment: I made it! Thank you very much for your sharing link, and I should have read more documents...